# g++ mysql linker error

Tags: c++, linker, g++, libmysql

I am trying to compile a program written in c++ with the following command line:

```
g++ test.cpp pugixml-1.0/src/pugixml.cpp -lcurl -lmysqlclient -lmysqlcppconn-static -lboost_thread
```

This goes all well on a Debian 32 Bit machine, but fails in Ubuntu 64 Bit and I have no clue why. I have installed all required packages for the usage of mysql. The error message looks like the following:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libmysqlcppconn-static.a(mysql_client_api.cpp.o): In function `sql::mysql::NativeAPI::LibmysqlStaticProxy::thread_init()':
(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `mysql_thread_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libmysqlcppconn-static.a(mysql_client_api.cpp.o): In function `sql::mysql::NativeAPI::LibmysqlStaticProxy::thread_end()':
(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `mysql_thread_end'
etc. ...
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The message is quite long and all lines look quite similar with changing references ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to inverse the order of `-lmysqlclient` `-lmysqlcppconn-static` in your linker call.

If object A needs symbols from object B, A must be in front of B in the linker command line.

Comment: @mike To understand why the order matters, you might want to read this: http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html